# State update not finised before other update starts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have this object:

```
{
  "Widget1": "notes",
  "Widget2": "clock",
  "Widget3": "weather",
}
```

It is transferred to my react app via a rest API.

```
const Widgets: React.FC = () => {
  interface DataType {
    [key: string]: string;
  }

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<DataType>();

  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:1202/data")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          setData(json);
          console.log("json", json);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
    setIsLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  const [currentWidget1, setCurrentWidget1] = React.useState<string>("wetter");
  const widget1Handler = (widget: string) => {};

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return (
       <div>loading...<div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
       <component data={data}></component>
    );
  }
};
export default Widgets;
```

The problem is that apparently it takes longer for `setData` to be updated than for `setIsLoaded` to update. 
So `component` is loaded before the data is stored in the data object.
Is there a quick fix for that?

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous, so the synchronous code that's after its line will get executed immediatly, then sometimes later, `fetch`'s promise will resolve (or reject) and `setData` will get called.

Comment: That said, you could probably just use the `data` for your check and remove `isLoaded`. `if (!data) return <div>loading...<div>;`

Answer (score -1):

You can check if there is data then set state: data && setData(json)

Comment: of course you need to write another useEffect which has dependency [data] and put above mentioned logic there... But the right way for this case is to remove your state for loaded and just conditionally render jsx with data: return !!data ? (your page with data) : (loading page)

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, you can use something like

```
if (Object.keys(data) > 0) {
  <Component data={data}></Component>
}
else {
  <div>loading...<div>
}
```

No Need to use `isLoaded`

FYI: React Components are always called with first character in uppercase `Component`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: In your useState you can use default value setter. like,

```const [data = {}, setData] = React.useState<DataType>();```

Comment: Or you can also use something like following,

`if (data && Object.keys(data) > 0) ...`